# Finger swipe not being detected on Windows phone: Code issue or phone issue?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, game-physics, user-experience

I have a game I'm making a mobile version of and I'm having trouble detecting screen swipes. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my outdated Windows phone that I'm testing on, or if it's a programmatic issue. I'd like to rule out the latter and hopefully get some suggestions.

Repro steps:

1. Open http://playclassicsnake.com/play on a mobile device
2. On the grid that the snake (the 3 green blocks) is living on, try swiping up, left, right or down
3. Get an alert that says "Tap detected" instead of an alert indicating that you swept a direction

My test code that produces the above is

```
// if mobile screen, set up event listeners for screen swipes to change snake's direction
var mc = new Hammer(document.getElementById('snake-board-holder')); // http://hammerjs.github.io/api/
mc.on('swipeleft', function (ev) {
    alert("Detected left swipe");
});
mc.on('swiperight', function (ev) {
    alert("Detected right swipe");
});
mc.on('swipeup', function (ev) {
    alert("Detected up swipe");
});
mc.on('swipedown', function (ev) {
    alert("Detected down swipe");
});
mc.on('tap', function (ev) { alert('Tap detected'); }); // TEST 
mc.on('pinch', function (ev) { alert('Pinch detected') }); // TEST
```

which uses an API with relevant documentation and example

- http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/
- http://codepen.io/jtangelder/pen/lgELw

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Is there a better way of controlling the movement than detecting finger swipes?

Comment: *"my outdated Windows phone"* .. Which phone , and especially, which version of WP?

Comment: @GolezTrol Just checked. "Windows Phone, NOKIA Lumia 521, T-Mobile, Windows Phone 8.0, 480x800"

Comment: I tested in in WP8.1, with a Huawei Ascend W2 (also 480x800). Left and Right swipe work. The other swipes result in scrolling. Pinch doesn't work, tap does. The events that do work, work poorly sometimes, especially when I try to pinch, it takes a while before the other gestures work again.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for the info!